# Why does my update query that works in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio not work as a Prepared Query in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a Table `[Name Table]` and an associated table `workSchedule`.  I'm using Hibernate 3.6.7.Final to generate my query. The result is:

```
update Personnel.dbo.[Name Table] set workSchedule=? where [Name IRC]=?
```

Which throws an Exception:

11-22@10:30:41 WARN  [] JDBCExceptionReporter      - SQL Error: 8624, SQLState: S0001
11-22@10:30:41 ERROR [] JDBCExceptionReporter      - Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.

`[Name Table].workSchedule` is a foreign key defined thus:

```
ALTER TABLE [Name Table] ADD workSchedule VARCHAR(34) 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES workSchedule(id);
```

`workSchedule.id` is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE workSchedule
( /* format = letter-days-lunch EX: A-5-1 */   
  id AS CASE lunch
         WHEN 1 THEN scheduleLetter+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, scheduleDays)+'-'+'1'
         ELSE scheduleLetter+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, scheduleDays)+'-'+'5'
        END PERSISTED NOT NULL,
/* rest of table follows */
);
```

If I copy paste the above update query into SSMS and plug values directly in for the ?s it works.

**UPDATE:**
I just tried changing out the PRIMARY KEY of the table `WorkSchedule` for an INT IDENTITY column.  I left renamed `id` to shift and otherwise left it as column on the table.  I also updated both POJO's and .hbm.xml files. The update query still fails, with the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm listing this as an answer because it's what I ended up doing to solve my problem.

I completely removed the calculated field on WorkSchedule.
I implemented the calcualations as a getter in the the POJO instead.
Re-tooled `workschedule` to use an IDENTITY for the PK
and re-linked `[Name Table]` to the new IDENTITY field instead. now it all works.